# Combobox record source from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Combobox can be done if SQL Server table is linked. I want to remove table link.  What is the record source of combobox which will get list from SQL Server directly? I am using Access 2013 and SQL Server 2014 Express. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a select query as a callback query and use that as rowsource for the combobox.

The query will pull the records "directly" from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

There not really a practical means to do this that will “help” performance. However, you can certainly build a pass-through query. That means the local Access query will contain RAW t-sql (sql server syntax). This can often increase performance.

Another tip if the query in question has more than one table, then building a SQL view, and then linking to that view works well. You will STILL have a local link that appears as a linked table, and you put JUST the view name in the combo box row source.

You can build in code a DAO (or ADO) recordset, and then assign that recordset directly to the data source of the combo box, but such additional coding does NOT yield any more performance then using a view or a pass-through query (and the view or the pass-through query does not take any code, is less work and results in the same performance anyway).

So at the end of the day simply use a linked table, or as noted a linked view.